# SymmetricDS scheduled sync

Tags: postgresql, replication, symmetric-ds

I am trying to configure SymmetricDS to run a scheduled replication from one postgres database to another.

I've seen people suggesting doing that by setting these fields in node config:

```
job.routing.period.time.ms
job.push.period.time.ms
job.pull.period.time.ms
```

Or by creating time windows for replication in this table:

```
NODE_GROUP_CHANNEL_WINDOW
```

The first options seems to be better as I don't want to specify end time of replication. The issue is that I want to only replicate the database from **one point in time**, when the replication starts, so the data integrity is preserved (eg. if the replication takes 2h and there are changes made to the source DB after the replication had started I want them to be replicated in the next cycle)
Should I set all of these values to 24h, or does the routing job need to run more frequently?

While trying to test this I also ran into the following issue - not all the data has been replicated in single scheduled sync (the database is quite large):

> Reached the total byte threshold after 3 of 5 batches were extracted
>   for node '001'.  The remaining batches will be extracted on a
>   subsequent sync

How to disable the limitation? I know of 3 properties of each channel but I'm not sure how to configure them.

```
MAX_BATCH_SIZE
MAX_BATCH_TO_SEND
MAX_DATA_TO_ROUTE
```

The other thing I am not certain about is how to assign tables to routers and channels in order to achieve what I specified above.